# Can I monitor when an app has been closed? For example when a user closes Maps(or any other app) can I make a popup come up saying "you closed maps"

Tags: java, android

I basically want to add a feature to an app I am making but it would require me to know when the user closes certain apps. For example if the user closes any of the following; Maps, Firefox, Facebook, and Camera, A yes/no notification, kinda specific to the app, would come up for the user to answer.

It's something that sounds complicated i know but im pretty sure I've seen it done on a few android apps before.

Thanks

edit: so i was thinking since tasker can perform a task upon opening an app and then stopping the task when closing the app i can do what i want right?

Comment: i'd be really surprised if there was a way to know when an arbitrary app opens or closes. that's be a privacy concern. i could track what apps you are running on your device. of course, if you have a home screen replacement type of app, it can tell when you launch an app, because it's the thing that's launching the app.

Comment: Its possible to do with Tasker though. For example when i close angry birds i can get it to display "you closed angry birds" or a hundred different things. That app doesnt even require root.

Comment: one unlikely but possible scenario is that it's watching logcat output. there are fairly well defined messages printed when things are started / stopped. again, i don't think this is likely.

Answer (score 0):

The closest option available for monitoring the status of other applications and packages is through the use of a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) registered to listen for [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) related to packages or applications. I looked through the intents available (the actions are constants with names starting with `ACTION_`), and none were directly related to another application closing, however you may be able to capture something, such as a changed battery status, that can look at the status of running applications in question.